# How to map through an array of objects and add value to each other in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to sum one specific value from my array of objects.

my array:

```
const myArray = [
{package_id: 1, width: "30"},
{package_id: 2, width: "20"},
{package_id: 3, width: "50"}
]
```

The value I would like to achive is the width. So the result would be 100
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it easily with a reduce function.

```js
yourArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc + parseInt(curr.width, 10);
}, 0);
```